# Using printk to display the function caller's name in kernel space

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

Normally to print the current function executing in `start_kernel` we can use `printk("%s %d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)` with `early_printk` enabled. But is there any way to print the caller's name by replacing `__FUNCTION__` with something else.This is for ARM architecture. I have used `__builtin_return_address(1)` in one of functions of `start_kernel` which does not work in ARM since ARM stores return address in R14.

And I have also tried printing symbol name like `char sym[KSYM_SYMBOL_LEN];`  `sprint_symbol(sym,(unsigned long)tick_init);` after `tick_init` function call. But it does not work. I think its because kallsyms is not present so early during bootup process. Is there any way to make it work.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` macro is replaced by the compiler with constant string, and *doesn't require dynamic resolution*. Resolving **caller** function's name cannot be performed during compilation, such **requires dynamic resolution** in any case. As for `__builtin_return_address`, you should use `0` argument for get address within *caller function*. And this call works on any architecture (at least, this is stated in [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html)).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I want an alternative for `__builtin_return_address(1)` in ARM. I know argument 0 works well for getting current function.

Comment: `I know argument 0 works well for getting current function.` - Argument 0 works well for getting **caller** function. That is, argument 1 would get *caller of the caller*. Is this what you actually want?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes but it does not work in ARM.

Comment: Well, then how `__builtin_return_address(1)` problem is related with `__FUNCTION__` problem and with *symbol resolving*? As you unable to obtain any address, what do you want to resolve into symbol name? Please, concentrate in question on **single problem**, until problems are related, so resolving one of them affects on another.

Comment: @Tsyvarev See `__FUNCTION__` and  `__builtin_return_address(0)` have same functionality i.e., they give the current function name/address. What I want is to get the caller function's (which is calling the current function) address/name somehow in ARM. Please understand the question.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` returns *name* of the **CURRENT** function. `__builtin_return_address(0)` returns *address* in a **CALLER** (not in a *current*) function. Sorry for uppercase, but this have already been empasized in my previous comments.